# Which is the best way to add data to a database?

Tags: php, sql

```
$user='root';

try{
$pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',$user);
$pdo->exec('set character set utf8');
}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}

//using bound variables?
$stmt=$pdo->prepare('insert into test(name) value(:name)');
$stmt->bindParam(':name',$_POST['name']);
$stmt->execute();

//using named parameters
$stmt=$pdo->prepare('insert into test(name) value(:name)');
$stmt->execute(array(':name'=>$_POST['name']));

//using placeholders
$stmt=$pdo->prepare('insert into test(name) value(?)');
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['name']));

//using bound parameters w/ placeholders
$stmt=$pdo->prepare('insert into test(name) value(?)');
$stmt->bindParam($_POST['name']);
$stmt->execute();
```

I just want to know what is the best to use for my as a PHP starter, I'm just confused what to use and I want to know what is the best and commonly use.

Comment: They all work equally "best", there's hardly a definitive answer here.

Comment: You should read the documentation, learn everything about them and their differences. And then use the one that seems the most apropriate to you :) I do know that this is not the answare you ware looking for, but you should be aware of all possibilities, and use the one that seems the most appropriate to you.

Comment: When you say "best" what do you mean?

Comment: i want to know what is commonly used by most php developers?

Comment: yes sir i read just want to know what is commonly used by developers :)

Comment: side-note: please don't use `exec(set character set utf8)`. Your best option is to use charset=utf8 in the DSN when connecting to mysql. This requires php 5.3.6+. But even if you have to maintain backwards compatibility there are better options than an `set character set` statement.

Comment: Thank you sir, that's what i really need, like this $pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset-utf8',$user); and remove my exec(set character set utf8) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the second method the best:

```
//using named parameters
$stmt=$pdo->prepare('insert into test(name) value(:name)');
$stmt->execute(array(':name'=>$_POST['name']));
```

You have named params, so you know what is what in the array - I hate looking at five or more `?` in the code and trying to work out if the order is right, and it takes less lines of code to throw in an array and execute it all at the same time than going through many `->bindParam()` lines.

If this option was off the table though, I would go through the many lines of `->bindParam()` over the others.

This question comes down to personal preference. Choose what is best for you, what is easy to read and understand (especially if you come back to it weeks or months later) and what is easy to read for *others* who might have to pick through your code to debug it.

Edit: Nothing works *faster* as such. Putting the query together might take *milliseconds* longer one way or the other, but the queries will take the same amount of time to execute on the database. Faster really isn't something to look at here.

Comment: so what works faster? so it is best to use array(':name',$_POST['name'])? for the situation like registering a user? thanks :)

Comment: @SuiGo Happy to offer any insight that I can. I am actually much more happy to see these sorts of questions being asked as it means you are really thinking about *how* your code works and trying to write the best code possible - and it is often easier to get into the right habits starting off than to change them down the track.

Comment: Yes sir i really want to know. specially to those people who are been doing this for many years.. :), I want to know their suggestion or advice that could help me improve :))

Answer (score 2):

The answer comes down to one thing - personal preference. They all work as intended and equally give the same result, but "how you write it" is entirely up to what you're more comfortable with - and potentially the others who may (eventually) work with your code as well.

My own personal opinion, I think that named parameters are the best as it makes it very clear what value you're setting. With a single parameter in a query, it may be pointless - but when there are 10+, it can come in handy.

Comment: Thank you sir, i just need what are commonly used by dev's

Comment: @SuiGo No problem! I work with this stuff on a daily basis, and with many others who do too. Almost all of us have our own opinions though, so again - it's what you like the most =]

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the first of the four. It's clear what you're doing, so your code will prove easier to maintain. Using arrays is useful when the array is already exists, and all values are going to be used in the query. Still, when writing code, you *will* be confronted with bugs. And debugging queries that use the `?` placeholders can be a pain.

When it comes to performance, there's not an awful lot of difference between any of the 4 approaches, but there are some differences:

In 2 of the 4 examples you're creating an array. Creating arrays is cheap, but not free. 
When using `bindParam`, you can specify the data type easily (just browse through the PDO predefined constanstants). Most of the time this won't make that big of a difference, but in cases where a full table scan is being preformed, it is generally better to not have MySQL doing type conversion.

So on performance: don't construct new arrays if you don't have to and set the set the correct data-type if at all possible.

On code-quality: named parameters generally make your life easier, so I'd advise you to use them as much as you can